# Doctrine nest multiple joins

Tags: join, symfony1, doctrine

I am  trying to optimize a symfony application with Doctrine. I've stumbled upon the following problem:

In the view I used $project->getProgress(); but by doing this the number of queries increase as there are more projects. So I tried to put the progress into the projects query(overriding the findAll method) with a left join, but this didn't work out. The number of queries actually increased.

```
public function findAll($hydrationMode = null)
{
    $q = $this->createQuery('p')
                    ->leftJoin('p.progress pr')
                    ->leftJoin('pr.sfGuardUser u')
                    ->leftJoin('p.raws r')
                    ->leftJoin('p.series');
    return $q->execute(array(), $hydrationMode);
}
```

This is the result I'm trying to create with the least possible amount of queries:

```
array() {
  [0]=>
  array() {
    ["id"]=> string(1) "1"
    ...
    ["progress"]=>
    array() {
        array() {
            array() { progress1 }
            array() { progress2 }
            array() { progress3 }
            ....
        }
    }
  }
```

I've looked through the documentation of both symfony and Doctrine and couldn't find my answer. I've also searched on google for quite a while. (I've been looking for a solution for over a few months now) I hope I've described my problem good enough.

schema.yml:

```
projects:
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
  columns:
    user_id: integer(4)
    series_id: bigint
    pages: int
    chapter: string
    translators_id: bigint
    proofreaders_id: bigint
    cleaners_id: bigint
    typesetters_id: bigint
    raws_id: bigint
    hide_project: bool
    complete: bool
  relations:
    sfGuardUser:
      local: user_id
      foreign: id
      onDelete: CASCADE
    series:
      local: series_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
      foreignType: many
      onDelete: CASCADE
    progress:
      local: id
      foreign: projects_id
      onDelete: CASCADE
      type: one
      foreignType: many

projectsProgress:
  actAs: [Timestampable]
  columns:
    projects_id: bigint
    user_id: integer(4)
    job:
      type: enum
      notnull: true
      values: [tl,pr,cl,ts]
    beginpage: int
    endpage: int
    complete: bool
    file: string
    url: clob
  relations:
    sfGuardUser:
      local: user_id
      foreign: id
      onDelete: CASCADE
    projects:
      local: projects_id
      foreign: id
      onDelete: CASCADE
      foreignAlias: progress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of using hydrate mode is that you could fetch data that wont use. I don't really know how doctrine fetch all data but assume that for each project brings all required data adding, at least, one more query...

For complex query's (and optimization) i prefer doing a manual query and manage to bring all needed data in one query, for example:

```
$query = "SELECT ... FROM projects p LEFT JOIN progress pr (LEFT JOIN sfGuardUser u (LEFT JOIN...) ON pr.user_id = u.id ) ON p.id = pr.projects_id"

$rs = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection()->fetchAssoc($query);
```

being *$rs* an array with selected data. Having all data you can make an array as you like, but remember that this way you do one query (reducing the db load) but add some time machine  parsing the array.

Comment: I managed to decrease the load time by 100-150ms by rewriting the code like this: http://pastebin.com/rS2v2nSF
Is this the best way to do it or are there better ways?

Comment: I'm read the code. How many projects are we talking about? Because this way you transfer the db load to the parsing load and you maybe aren't using all projects (if so, filter them). Sometimes is better to have a little more query's and less parsing but always depends on how many data are. For example, you can do 2 query's: one bringing the project data (the if block) and another bringing the progress and raws data. The way to optimize query's is reducing join tables. Check http://pastebin.com/svXux2pv

Comment: I've seen your code. We are talking about 1 to 20 open projects, I need all projects since this page is a list which shows the progress of each open project. (forgot to add the where condition to filter out the completed ones) Load time for the current page is now 450ms. I'll try to play with your code, there's something with the sql that needs to be fixed. I'll compare the load times between the two.

Comment: Both take functions take around 38ms to complete, which is much faster than before. Thanks! Do you have any idea how to speed up the view? it's the only thing left that is slowing everything down. (can't cache because the data is dynamic)

Comment: Nice :) The only way that I think to speed up views is reducing *foreach's *, *if's*, etc. to make it as simple as it can be. Loading only js that will be use and reducing images sizes. There are a lot of best practices of speeding up sites, just use google :) For example check http://bit.ly/hgOcOm

Comment: Thanks =) But is it normal that the bit.ly link is linking to this page?

Comment: There is no need to break out of Doctrine for the query outlined in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the query that fetches the `Project` object to include the joins. Conventionally, queries that fetch `Project` objects should be placed in `ProjectTable`.

If you want to modify all queries or subsets of queries of `Project`, look into [Doctrine Query Execution Listeners](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/event-listeners/en#connection-listeners%3aquery-execution-listeners).

Comment: If I modify the query, the amount of queries increase from 17 to 253. And the subset of progress is always empty.